# JavaScript: Send file to defined network printer

Tags: javascript, ajax, networking, printing

I was asked if it is possible to develop a JS solution where I access a network printer through the client. so, let's say I have a webservice which is available to certain customers and it provides the function to print a report (or something similar) to a user defined network printer (the user tells what domain and printername to print on)...

is this possible in any way? the best solution would be if it could be done through something like an Ajax request ;)

Comment: I don'r understand. Most browsers allow the user to right click, and select "print" from a drop down menu. At that time the user can select a specific printer, including network printers, or can print to PDF file. Pages that do not print well in their current format can/should include a link that takes the user to another version of the same page without any problematic visual elements (like unnecessary fancy backgrounds).  Why is this existing capability insufficient?  Why is anything additional needed?

Comment: it insufficient as it could possibly be a cashier module, which is running through a webservice and should print directly to the receiptprinter which is next to the cashier... the cashier wouldn't have the time, nor the nerves to click any additional buttons only to print a simple receipt - instead it should be printed directly. BUT all this should be implemented through an online (internet, no intranet) webservice ;)

Comment: Calling window.print() I think is the most you can easily do.  This saves the step of right clicking.  The printing still has to be confirmed. If the printer instead talks to your application server, which is not on-site, you are going to need to secure that link.  On the other hand, selling preconfigured receipt printers or customized VPN boxes that go between your network the internet and the printer could create lock-in to your product, and maybe you could mark them up as well. Of course, some customers recognize and avoid lock-in.

Comment: Maybe there is something in here you could use somehow... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing

Comment: thanks for the link, although it won't help me with my actual problem very much, it's a good knowledge base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but probably not in the way you want.  Your best bet is to use server-side scripting to print to the printer.  The problem is, modern web-browsers have lots of security features that don't allow things like this.

The only way I can think of to get around this is by using a printer that:
1) Accepts HTTP or FTP uploaded print jobs.
2) Is in the some DNS domain as the website so the anti-cross site scripting protections on the browser don't stop you.

Again though, you'd be much better off with some sort of server-side solution, or maybe writing a program or custom plugin to run on the client.

Comment: I see your point and I'd agree with that, except it is required to not have anything other than the webservice. nothing "extra" to install on the client machine... oh - and the webservice is not placed within an intranet (not the same DNS), but a fully webservice in "the cloud"...

Comment: In that case, I think your only option is to only support printers that support http/ftp, or maybe you might use some sort of 3rd party print service like AirPrint (Apple) or whatever Google's created to compete with that.